# Compilation Error for Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I just started working on reactjs, wrote my first config file and seem to get this error. Posted an imiage of the cmd error as well. 
My webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {

entry:{
    app: './src/app.js'
},
output:{
    filename: 'public/build/bundle.js',
    sourceMapFileName: 'public/build/bundle.map' 
},
devtool: '#source-map',
module: {
    loaders: 
    [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['react','es2015']
            }
        }
     ]
   } 
}
```

[Error while compiling using command 'webpack'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiCpZ.png)

Comment: Removed sourceMapFileName from config file, webpack version 2 and greater automatically created a .map file for me on compilation.

Comment: If your problem is resolved with this, please mark the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be a lowercase **n** in `sourceMapFileName` so instead it should be `sourceMapFilename`